# Workaround for the Stream.concat bug

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When Stream.concat is commented out, createLazyStream works as expected, it is initialized only when terminal operations are applied.

But if you uncomment Stream.concat line, then you will see that both streams were initialized even without actual usage (no terminal operations applied)

This is java bug, right?
What is a workaround?

```
@Test
public void testConcat() {

    Stream<Integer> stream = createLazyStream();
    // Stream<Integer> result = Stream.concat(stream, createLazyStream());

}

private Stream<Integer> createLazyStream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(() -> {

        System.out.println("initializing stream");
        return IntStream.range(1,10).spliterator();

    }, Spliterator.ORDERED, false);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stream is not evaluated, just the lambda. This is done in the Constructor of `ConcatSpliterator`, to test if the new stream is sized:

```
unsized = aSpliterator.estimateSize() + bSpliterator.estimateSize() < 0;
```

And to call `estimateSize`, you need the spliterator, so it calls the lambda to get it.

You can see this by adding `Thread.dumpStack()` to the lambda:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1333)
    at test.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:19)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$DelegatingSpliterator.get(StreamSpliterators.java:513)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$DelegatingSpliterator.estimateSize(StreamSpliterators.java:536)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.<init>(Streams.java:713)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator$OfRef.<init>(Streams.java:781)
    at java.util.stream.Stream.concat(Stream.java:1080)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

In reality, your test is flawed. If you want to see if the stream is evaluated, you could add `peek` before returning it.

```
return StreamSupport.stream(() -> {
    return IntStream.range(1,10).peek(i -> System.out.println("peek")).spliterator();

}, Spliterator.ORDERED, false);
```

Now you will see that there is still no output when you uncomment that line.

---

It does seem like this is wrongly documented though (a 'bug' in the documentation). From the documentation of that `StreamSupport.stream` method ([Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.function.Supplier-int-boolean-)):

> The Supplier.get() method will be invoked on the supplier no more than once, and only after the terminal operation of the stream pipeline commences.

Comment: _and only after the terminal operation of the stream pipeline commences_ this statement is not valid. I created deferred spliterator with predefined infinite estimate, now it works as expected, actual stream is created only when terminal operation is applied

Comment: The cited source code line calls `estimateSize()` on two **spliterators**, not two streams. In other words, *before* that, `Stream.spliterator()` had been called, which **is** a terminal operation, so it’s not contradicting the cited documentation part. It’s interesting that the source streams try to preserve the laziness beyond that point which is destroyed in the `ConcatSpliterator`’s constructor, but these are implementation details. It’s the documentation of `concat`, which doesn’t properly tell the impacts…